# Trying to understand why I can't round to 2 decimal places in one code but can in another thats virtually the same

Tags: java, rounding

I am writing a few java classes for a uni assignment and am having some trouble understanding what is going behind the scenes when I am trying to round to 2 decimal places. I have searched around but can't seem to find an answer that solves this particular version of the problem. So my code asks users to input prices into a cash register program and then prints the total price as well as the number of items. The total price has to be stored as an integer value (i.e 3.21 would be 321) but then outputted as a decimal value at the end. Here's my code:

```
public class CashRegister_Re_Implementation {

private double totalPrice;
private int itemCount;

CashRegister_Re_Implementation() {    
    totalPrice = 0;
    itemCount = 0;
}

public double getTotal() {
    String roundOff = String.format("%.2f", ((totalPrice * 100) / 10000));
    double newDecimal;
    newDecimal = Double.parseDouble(roundOff);
    return newDecimal;
}

public int getItemCount() {    
    return itemCount;
}

public void addItem(double price) {
    totalPrice += price * 100;   
    itemCount++;
}
}

class CashRegisterTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    CashRegister_Re_Implementation reg1 = new CashRegister_Re_Implementation();

    int count1 = 0;
    System.out.println("Register 1 (2 items)");
    while (count1 < 2) {
        System.out.print("Item price: £");
        double price = scan.nextDouble();
        reg1.addItem(price);
        count1++;
    }

    CashRegister_Re_Implementation reg2 = new CashRegister_Re_Implementation();

    int count2 = 0;
    System.out.println("\nRegister 2 (2 items)");
    while (count2 < 2) {
        System.out.print("Item price: £");
        double price = scan.nextDouble();
        reg2.addItem(price);
        count2++;
    }

    CashRegister_Re_Implementation reg3 = new CashRegister_Re_Implementation();

    int count3 = 0;
    System.out.println("\nRegister 2 (2 items)");
    while (count3 < 2) {
        System.out.print("Item price: £");
        double price = scan.nextDouble();
        reg3.addItem(price);
        count3++;
    }

    System.out.println("\nFirst register. Total price: £" + reg1.getTotal() + "p for " + reg1.getItemCount() + " items");
    System.out.println("Second register. Total price: £" + reg2.getTotal() + "p for " + reg2.getItemCount() + " items");
    System.out.println("Third register. Total price: £" + reg3.getTotal() + "p for " + reg3.getItemCount() + " items");
}
}
```

It works fine except that if I enter all 1.00 I get this output:

> ```
> Register 1 (2 items)
> Item price: £1.00
> Item price: £1.00
>
> Register 2 (2 items)
> Item price: £1.00
> Item price: £1.00
>
> Register 2 (2 items)
> Item price: £1.00
> Item price: £1.00
>
> First register Total price: £2.0p for 2 items
> Second register Total price: £2.0p for 2 items
> Third register Total price: £2.0p for 2 items
> ```

Why am I getting £2.0 instead of £2.00?

I wrote this separately and it works absolutely fine:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    double x = 100;
    double y = 100;
    double z = x + y;
    String roundOff = String.format("%.2f", z);
    System.out.println(roundOff);
}
```

Output:

> ```
> 200.00
>
> Process finished with exit code 0
> ```

Why can't I get £2.00 in the exercise? Many thanks for any time taken to read all this :p

Comment: `getTotal` returns a `double` and you're concatenating that value without formatting...

Comment: Don't use `double` for currency. Use `int` in lowest denomination.

Comment: `Double.parseDouble("2.00");` gives `2.0`.

Comment: Sure thing - in general you should do all your calculations first and only do the formatting very last before display.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your method `getTotal` has a return type of `double` but while concatenating the value in `System.out.println` you don't use formatting.

```
public double getTotal() {
    String roundOff = String.format("%.2f", ((totalPrice * 100) / 10000));
    double newDecimal;
    newDecimal = Double.parseDouble(roundOff);
    return newDecimal;
}
```

You should either return the formatted string from above method or change the print statements as follows:

```
System.out.println("\nFirst register. Total price: £" + String.format("%.2f", ((reg1.getTotal() * 100) / 10000)) + "p for " + reg1.getItemCount() + " items");
System.out.println("Second register. Total price: £" + String.format("%.2f", ((reg2.getTotal() * 100) / 10000)) + "p for " + reg2.getItemCount() + " items");
System.out.println("Third register. Total price: £" + String.format("%.2f", ((reg3.getTotal() * 100) / 10000)) + "p for " + reg3.getItemCount() + " items");
```

**Note** that a formatter has now been applied to the return value that you get from the method `getTotal()`.

Comment: Hi thanks for reply. The trouble with that is I'm supposed to make the changes within the methods themselves, the CashRegisterTest class is being treated a user who is testing my code. The user may not necessarily do the formatting so it would need to be done behind the scenes

Comment: I also can't change the return types of any the methods

Comment: @AndrewMacmillan if you cannot change the definition of `getTotal` method and neither the format of the output, then what you're asking is impossible. Take into account that `1.0` and `1.000000000000000` are the same. The string representation is only for us humans to have a better understanding of the data.

Comment: Ah mmmmm really? No wonder it won't work! I mean I can get it to work easily enough by putting the formatting in the print out as is mentioned but I didn't think that was what they were asking for. Many thanks I'll email my tutor to get some more clarity if you say that this is impossible

Answer (score 0):

For a better reusability you should outline the first line in the method `getTotal()` in a new method like `getTotalFormatted()`. So you can use it in your rounding-algorithm and for printing too.

Comment: Hi, again the trouble is that I have to use only these methods in the format that they are in. We wrote a program earlier and now we have to use the same code to re-implement it to store the value of totalPrice as an integer. Sorry should have made this clear in the question